# Android DataBinding with different layout in adapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using gridview with different layout in BaseAdapter. If views get reused at that time i got CastException. How can i resolve this?

My Adapter code is :

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (position == 0) {
        if(v == null){
            TestItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.
                    inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), R.layout.test_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.view = binding.getRoot();
        } else {
            holder = (GridViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
    } else {
        if(v == null){
            TestItem2Binding binding = DataBindingUtil.
                    inflate(LayoutInflater.from(mContext), R.layout.test2_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.view = binding.getRoot();
        } else {
            holder = (GridViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
    }
    setImage(holder.imageView, items.get(position));
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting tag to your view. You are requesting a tag without setting it. 
Add this line `v.setTag(holder)` after both of your lines `holder.view = binding.getRoot();`

If it does not work then try `v.setTag(holder.view)`